# best rdf database to quickly start a semantic web

Tags: rdf, semantics, sparql

Hipal! I'm a newbee to semantic web. I wanna choose a RDF database which meets the **Resource Description Framework** and supports **SPARQL**.There are 4store,AllegroGraph etc. which one is better,more easier to start and has good documents(with Python in Ubuntu) for building a semantic web for Image Search. It's better to display visual graphs of a store's resources.Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your question is rather broad, and also very hard to answer objectively. No doubt different people will find different tools 'better'. It would help if you could tell a little bit more about what you want to use the RDF database for, what programming environment you prefer, etc.

Comment: You can also find a very useful list of tools and libraries for SW application development here: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/75/which-tools-and-libraries-do-you-use-to-develop-semantic-web-applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenRDF Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/) is an open-source framework for RDF that offers full SPARQL 1.1 support and has vendor-neutral access APIs to multiple triplestore solutions. Although Sesame is in Java, it can be easily accessed from Python (see [this blog post by Jeni Tennisson](http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/153) for a quick walkthrough).

Sesame is a Java web application, to set up simply install Tomcat and deploy the Sesame WAR file. See the [Sesame user documentation](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/) for installation, configuration, and usage instructions.

Comment: If vs 4store,AllegroGraph, what's difference between them?

Comment: @David, they're different products, each having their strengths and weaknesses. But since you are a beginner I doubt that those differences are really all that significant for you. To learn this stuff, pretty much any of those tools will do. Pick one you like the look of.

Answer (score 2):

Virtuoso is dead simple to setup on ubuntu:

http://ods.openlinksw.com/wiki/main/Main/VOSUbuntuNotes

```
sudo aptitude install  virtuoso-opensource
```

Has lots of features and is very suitable for beginners

Comment: is there any particular resource that you used to get up to speed for the first time? because I'm actually having a hard time getting familiar with their web tools (conductor)

Comment: I agree that virtuoso is simple to setup. But, this is under GPL v2 license whereas Sesame is under BSD.

Answer (score 2):

[Stardog](http://stardog.com) is very easy to setup, unzip and you're done, and provides API bindings for both Sesame & Jena.  There is a [Python library](https://github.com/huyphan/pystardog) for Stardog's HTTP protocol and a Javascript version due soon.  It does not yet support SPARQL 1.1, that's due in a couple weeks, but it supports reasoning support for RDFS and all three OWL2 profiles.